# Set variable sheet name while linking to other workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 Excel files where fileA calculates the numbers from fileB.
In cell A1 in fileA, I would reference cell Z1, sheet 99 in fileB with:
='[fileB.xlsx]99'!$Z$1
and get the value from fileB. Let's say the value is 999.

Now the part I have a problem is where I want to be able to set in fileA the sheet number that it is referenced from. For example, if I key in 98 in fileA cell A2, the cell A1 reference would change to `='[fileB.xlsx]98'!$Z$1`.

That way the user for fileA would be able to update all their references (over multiple sheets) in fileA by just changing the number on fileA cell A2.

I've read up numerous variable/dynamic sheet solutions and non addresses this. Or I'm searching the keywords wrongly.

`INDIRECT` function doesn't work as it requires both files to be open. The user can only open fileA.

Comment: Is a formula solution required, or can VBA be used?

Comment: EXCEL workbooks with external links are **broken** workbooks, full of bugs and errors and miscalculations waiting to get someone fired. Accept it, and move on to a solution that doesn't use external links.

Comment: @jmac A formula solution please. :D

Pieter I have to work with what parameters I'm given. The ideal world is that this excel wouldn't even be needed, but unfortunately it is. The other solution whi8ch I'm trying to replace require way more manpower and time consumption. :S

Comment: @user2709352: What does "The user can only open fileA." mean **exactly**?  It is the nature of file systems and operating systems that a file must be *open* to be read, and EXCEL adheres to this. How do you expect it to read *fileB* without opening it?

Comment: Sorry, I have to agree with Pieter here. There is something seriously wrong if you are trying to do this with formulas. Any solution will be worse than the problem you are trying to solve. I have tried a dozen different workarounds, but none will do what you want.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Well my excel can do it without variables thrown in. Try making a new excel with a number on A1. Lets call it Book1. Save and close it. Then make a new excel in the same folder(for ease of explanation), and type anywhere =[Book1]sheet1!A1 , it should come out. While book1 is closed. For files in other directory, it will ask you to point to it. 

Give it a try, it opens up great possibilities! :D

Comment: @user2709352: Now try it without **Read** permission on the workbook, and tell me how that works.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens
I'm not sure where to find read permissions... I replied to pnuts that his index idea is a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
=INDEX('D:\Directory\Path\Folder\[fileB.xlsx]98'!$Z$1,1,1)
```

should be able to retrieve the contents of Z1 in fileB into fileA without opening fileB. It may not be possible, without code, to have the relevant sheet name determined by a value in A2 of fileA but Find and Replace may suit.

Comment: Hmmm, yea seems it will work. Find and Replace, good point. I just need to make sure they dont replace similar cells. :D
Will try, thanks!

Comment: IT WORKS!!
I used
=INDEX('B:\XXXX\[2013.xlsx]99'!$Z$9:$Z$222,K61)
and a K61 is set as
=MATCH(F65,'B:\XXXX\[2013.xlsx]99'!$D$9:$D$222,0)

This page helped on your index suggestion:
http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/